# SetParameters - An error occurred during local report processing

Tags: vb.net, parameters, report

this is the code:

```
    Dim ddate As New ReportParameter("date", StocksReports.ddate)
    Dim tdate As New ReportParameter("datetwo", StocksReports.tdate)
    Dim cname As New ReportParameter("cashier", StocksReports.cashier)


    Dim sheetParams As ReportParameter() = {ddate, tdate, cname}
    For Each params As ReportParameter In sheetParams
        ReportViewerstocks.LocalReport.SetParameters(sheetParams)
    Next
```

I have 2 reports which is sales and stocks. In sales form the code runs without error but whenever I run stocks form, I get this error: An error occurred during local report processing. The error in this line of code:

```
ReportViewerstocks.LocalReport.SetParameters(sheetParams)
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
 Dim sheetParams As ReportParameter() = {ddate, tdate, cname}
```

to this line

```
 Dim sheetParams() As ReportParameter = {ddate, tdate, cname}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to check `Reportpath` in your program:

[reportpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/libv0.png)
[check path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTIsn.png)
[check path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBrNU.png)